# $_POST form by clicking on pictures. And knows which picture was clicked

Tags: php, image, forms

I am trying to make a form whereby people are shown 6 pictures. I want the form to transfer two variables in a $_POST. I want to send a variable $word and the picture that was clicked on.

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out a way to do this. There aren't many tutorials on it.

Any direction would be helpful.

I am in the beginning stages and I have no clue what to try.

```
    echo "Select the word: ". $wordList[$newSD] . "</br></br>";

$stimuli = fetchStimuli($wordList, $newSD, 5);

echo "<form action='endtrial.php' method=POST id=trial>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($stimuli); $i++){
    if ($i == 0){
        $rowSet = 1;
        $newRow = 3;
    }
    echo "<img src='images/". $stimuli[$i] .".jpg' width='300' height='240'>";

    if ($rowSet == $newRow){
        echo "</br>";
        $newRow = $newRow * 2;
    }
    $rowSet++;
}
echo "</form>";
```

Ultimately I want to change the img tag into a picture that can be clicked and that sends `$wordList[$newSD]` and the picture that was clicked on as `$_POST` variables. Not sure where to turn.

Comment: I'd use JavaScript/jQuery on the front end to handle server requests (Ajax)

Comment: I don't really have exposure to AJAX. I don't really know how to use it. And maybe later it would be nice to have. it involves too much work for me now. I just need something functional right now.

The info will be handled on a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be to hard with a basic html form. This should help you on the way:

```
<?php
   $word = "Test";
   $images = [
       1 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
       2 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
       3 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
       4 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
       5 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
       6 => 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
   ];
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="word" value="<?= $word ?>">

    <p>
        Click on "<?= $word ?>"
    </p>

    <?php foreach ($images as $key => $src) : ?>
        <button type="submit" name="img" value="<?= $key ?>">
            <img src="<?= $src ?>">
        </button>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>



<?php
  var_dump($_POST); // eg. array(2) { ["word"]=> string(4) "Test" ["img"]=> string(1) "4" }
?>
```

So the word is send back by adding it as a hidden input. The images are placed inside a button, and by giving these a `name` and  `value` they will be sent along with the request.

You'll obviously need some styling on those buttons and stuff. And what you do with the posted values I leave up to you.

The code is untested, but you should be able to just paste it in a PHP page and I think it should run fine. Let me know if you encounter any errors or if you want me to explain anything in depth.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your description it did the trick!